# How to add a textbox value to variable from a userform?

Tags: excel, vba

I've created a userform named `UIAutotestHeader` and textbox named `pypath`. And on button click I'm trying to pass a value to a variable but getting `runtime error 424`. Any help please.

```
Sub LoopThroughFiles()
   Dim Path As String    
   UIAutotestHeader.Show
   Path = pypath.Value
   If pypath.Value = "" Then
       MsgBox "Please add a path having .py files."
   End If
End sub
```

Button click code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    UIAutotestHeader.Hide
End Sub
```

Comment: it doesn't know that pypath is a control, it thinks its a variable which doesn't have a value method. You need userform("formnamehere").controls("pypath").value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, see this helpful [RubberDuck Blog](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/) on working with UserForms, very helpful and applicable. This is what I'm basing my answer on.

---

Try to instantiate your userform using a `With` statement so that you have a captured instance of it where you have access to its various properties that you expose.

Note, in this case, you don't have to store your variables, as you still have access to them in your instance of your userform.  Here is an example below.

```
Sub LoopThroughFiles()
   With New UIAutotestHeader
        .Show
        If Not .IsCancelled Then
            If .PyPath = "" Then
                MsgBox "Please add a path having .py files."
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

---

In your Userform, you can expose the properties that you want to have access to. I also added the `IsCancelled` method to make sure the user didn't press cancel.

```
Option Explicit

Private cancelled As Boolean

Public Property Get PyPath() As String
    PyPath = pypath.Value
End Property

Public Property Get IsCancelled() As Boolean
    IsCancelled = cancelled
End Property

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Hide
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    If CloseMode = VbQueryClose.vbFormControlMenu Then
        Cancel = True
        OnCancel
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub OnCancel()
    cancelled = True
    Hide
End Sub
```

Comment: It was giving error `member already exists` at line `Public Property Get PyPath() As String` so changed `PyPath()` to `PyPath1()`. But `path` is empty.

Comment: That's because  I just used a variable `path` as an example. I'll edit my answer so that you can see how to use it getting it from your `pypath.Value`, which I assume is some control in your userform? Which in that case you could have a conflict of names. Have the property you want to be exposed be the name that would make sense to you.

Comment: Now could see value in `.pypath`. But unable access it after `With` block.

Comment: You could either use it within the `With` block and do your execution from there. The advantage there is that you don't have to declare additional variables, you have them already in your userform. Or, you can do like you did above and store that value into a variable `Path = .pypath`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
'In Standard Module
'------------------
Public sPath As String

Sub LoopThroughFiles()
Load UIAutotestHeader
sPath = UIAutotestHeader.pypath.Value
UIAutotestHeader.Show
End Sub

'In UserForm Module
Private Sub pypath_AfterUpdate()
If sPath = "" Then
    MsgBox "Please add a path having .py files."
End If
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
If sPath <> "" Then MsgBox sPath
sPath = ""
Unload UIAutotestHeader
End Sub
```

Comment: Here also `sPath` does not return anything.